# Asymptotic behaviour of error function

Tags: limits, probability-theory, analysis

I want to show that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{a\to\infty}\dfrac{\int_{a}^\infty e^{-y^2/2}dy}{\frac{1}{a}e^{-a^2/2}} = 1$$
My first instinct was to just calculate the antiderivative of the integral but after some research I've found out that this would involve the Gaussian error function which doesn't have a closed form, so I'm kind of stuck. I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: Oh my god that didn't even cross my mind, I'll try it out

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks worked out perfectly, kind of shocked I didn't think of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_a^\infty e^{-y^2/2}dy\right)=\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2/2}dy-\int_0^a e^{-y^2/2}dy\right)=0\;,$

$\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\left(\frac1a e^{-a^2/2}\right)=0\quad,$

$D_a\left(\int_a^\infty e^{-y^2/2}dy\right)=D_a\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2/2}dy-\int_0^a e^{-y^2/2}dy\right)=$

$\quad=-D_a\left(\int_0^a e^{-y^2/2}dy\right)=-e^{-a^2/2}\quad$ and

$D_a\left(\frac1a e^{-a^2/2}\right)=e^{-a^2/2}\left(-\frac1{a^2}-1\right)=-e^{-a^2/2}\left(\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\right)\ne0$

$\quad\text{for any }\,a>0\quad,$

by applying L’Hopital’s Rule, we get that

$\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\dfrac{\int_{a}^\infty e^{-y^2/2}dy}{\frac{1}{a}e^{-a^2/2}}= \lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\dfrac{-e^{-a^2/2}}{-e^{-a^2/2}\left(\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}\right)}=\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+1}=1\,.$